# How to make page transition

Tags: html, css-transitions, transition

I am making a website and I want to make it so that if you click on a button at the bottom of the page you go to a new .html file with a different layout, but I want it to look like that new page is sliding up so that it looks like a cool transition.

Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <p>Create a link of an image:
        <a href="default.asp">
            <img src="smiley.gif" alt="HTML tutorial" width="32" height="32">
        </a>
    </p>

    <p>No border around the image, but still a link:
        <a href="default.asp">
            <img border="0" src="smiley.gif" alt="HTML tutorial" width="32" height="32">
        </a>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I need it to be so that when you click on the picture it goes to a new page, but when it goes to that new page there is a "sliding up" transition.

Thanks!

Comment: @Shomz That's for transitions on a page, not between pages.

Comment: @Adrian I know, that's why I gave the definition... It also explains the jquery comment above.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an iFrame to accomplish this:

### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TheGAFF/hNYMr/)

I used [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) for the transition effects:

```
$("#myLink").click(function () {
    $('#newPage').transition({top: '0%' });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is possible for standard navigation.
Some options that should be possible:

1. Use JavaScript to navigate (either by putting all on the same page or through AJAX)
2. Put everything on the same page and use `:target` and CSS transitions

For option 1 you can still have reasonable URLs in the browser if you use the history API.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using something like this: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/

The only issue is that you may see a brief flash of the new page, which will then disappear, and then be transitioned in. This is more or less unavoidable without using `iframe`s or something similar (something I'm generally loathe to do).

Answer (score 0):

You could also try implementing something like a [vertical slider](http://ludovic.chabant.com/devblog/2009/11/02/fun-with-jquery-the-vertical-coda-slider/) , much like the [coda slider](http://kevinbatdorf.github.io/codaslider/)  but this one is developed for vertical scrolling. [Demo](http://ludovic.chabant.com/devblog_demos/verticalcodaslider/).

I tried making these kind of transitions full page and found it difficult. (But I'm a JQ N00B)

[Magic slider](http://orangenwerk.github.io/magic-slider/desc.html) Offers horizontal and vertical scrolling and could be easier to implement.

Also have a look at [this](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3PageTransitions/index.html#home) ([tutorial here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/30/page-transitions-with-css3/)) which might be a simple solution to what you need.

**Actually I think this last one is the closet to what you want**

Comment: That doesn't open a new .html file.  The concept of this thread is to go to a new .html file.